# Vim: long range movements

Tags: vim, range, line, goto

I've been using vim for a day so far, so I'm still learning the basic stuff and thinking on how to do such movement to go here and there, and so on.

For long screen movements, I've found the `nG` command (goto line `n`) to be quite handy, yet I was wondering if you (vimmers) usually use it, or if there are more efficient ways to do long travels with less inputs.

Also, I've learnt that you could enable relative line numbers to move easier with `nj` and `nk`. Do you actually use it instead of `nG` (if you happen to use it)?

Comment: It depends on what I'm editing. If you're looking for additional resources: There is a vim SO: http://vi.stackexchange.com/ I can also recommend the book "Practical VIM", which has a nice format for learning a bunch of little tricks without being to lengthy.

Comment: @SBI Oh indeed... I have seen other questions about vim on the regular stackoverflow, so I didn't bother to search anywhere else (I should have though). And thank you for the book. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you know the exact line number you want to go, the `nG` (the `n` is line number) would be the best way.

If not, there are many ways to do "long range" motion:

- `ctrl-d/u`
- `/pattern`
- `* or #`
- `)` (sentence)
- `}` (paragraph)
- `]` command `:h ]`
- `x%`  like `30%` go to the 30% position of the content
- `H, L, M` moves cursor on same screen (H:1st line, M:Middle, L:lastline)
- `....`

If the "long range" was still on the same screen, there is a nice plugin `EasyMotion`, you would like it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen briefly what EasyMotion's features offer, and indeed, it's really nice, I'll definitely use it if I stick with vim. Though I'm using QtCreator and its FakeVim plugin for now, I don't think it would be possible to install plugins on it... or is it ?